# CryptoAPI cypher data generated to big when input size is exactly aligned to BlockSize

Tags: c#, windows, encryption, ios6, cryptography

Can someone help explain the following?  In the attached code, when the input text to be encrypted is exactly aligned to 
the InputBlockSize of the ICryptoTransform, the result is 1 block larger than the input.
Why is that, and how can this be avoided.  I need to decrypt the data on another system (iOS6) where this additional block is not added or expected.

Output from code is right after the code segment.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace TestCryptoAPI
    {
             class Program
             {
                     private static AesCryptoServiceProvider _cryptoServiceProvider;

                     static void Main(string[] args)
                     {
                              var encryptionKey = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xae };
                              var initializationVector = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xd5 };
                              _cryptoServiceProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

                              _cryptoServiceProvider.Key = encryptionKey;
                              _cryptoServiceProvider.IV = initializationVector;
                              _cryptoServiceProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CFB;
                              _cryptoServiceProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                              Console.WriteLine("_cryptoServiceProvider.BlockSize={0}", _cryptoServiceProvider.BlockSize);
                              ICryptoTransform encryptor = _cryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor();
                              Console.WriteLine("encryptor.InputBlockSize={0}, encryptor.OutputBlockSize={1}", encryptor.InputBlockSize, encryptor.OutputBlockSize);

                              const string clearText15Chars = "123456789012345";
                              const string clearText16Chars = "1234567890123456";
                              const string clearText31Chars = "1234567890123456789012345678901";
                              const string clearText32Chars = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
                              const string clearText47Chars = "12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567";
                              const string clearText48Chars = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678";
                              const string clearText63Chars = "123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123";
                              const string clearText64Chars = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";

                              EncryptAndPrint(clearText15Chars);
                              EncryptAndPrint(clearText16Chars);
                              EncryptAndPrint(clearText31Chars);
                              EncryptAndPrint(clearText32Chars);
                              EncryptAndPrint(clearText47Chars);
                              EncryptAndPrint(clearText48Chars);
                              EncryptAndPrint(clearText63Chars);
                              EncryptAndPrint(clearText64Chars);
                     }

                     private static void EncryptAndPrint(string clearTextChars)
                     {
                              var cypherData = Encrypt(clearTextChars);
                              Console.WriteLine("ClearTextChars.Length={0}, CypherData.Length={1}, {2}", clearTextChars.Length, cypherData.Length, Convert.ToBase64String(cypherData));
                     }

                     private static byte[] Encrypt(string clearText15Chars)
                     {
                              var dataToEncrypt = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(clearText15Chars);
                              ICryptoTransform encryptor = _cryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor();

                              var cypherData = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(dataToEncrypt, 0, dataToEncrypt.Length);
                              return cypherData;
                     }
             }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
    _cryptoServiceProvider.BlockSize=128
    encryptor.InputBlockSize=16, encryptor.OutputBlockSize=16
    ClearTextChars.Length=15, CypherData.Length=16, u8UVUNITsRswDu+usR3/gA==
    ClearTextChars.Length=16, CypherData.Length=32, u8UVUNITsRswDu+usR3/t7WnO82YSBITPehPTgwYTcg=

    ClearTextChars.Length=31, CypherData.Length=32, u8UVUNITsRswDu+usR3/t5LDd7hM0jYQr5mv9BU/6rE=
    ClearTextChars.Length=32, CypherData.Length=48, u8UVUNITsRswDu+usR3/t5LDd7hM0jYQr5mv9BU/6oK3EUi+F5lNkLmPFLjyIRCz

    ClearTextChars.Length=47, CypherData.Length=48, u8UVUNITsRswDu+usR3/t5LDd7hM0jYQr5mv9BU/6oKUWgdedM8a5BDQMQtWF5eA
    ClearTextChars.Length=48, CypherData.Length=64, u8UVUNITsRswDu+usR3/t5LDd7hM0jYQr5mv9BU/6oKUWgdedM8a5BDQMQtWF5e5HTHV4UCSuS5YsTlhNZwt+g==

    ClearTextChars.Length=63, CypherData.Length=64, u8UVUNITsRswDu+usR3/t5LDd7hM0jYQr5mv9BU/6oKUWgdedM8a5BDQMQtWF5e5NMSh/6GlzSMfscnk1Sc4bg==
    ClearTextChars.Length=64, CypherData.Length=80, u8UVUNITsRswDu+usR3/t5LDd7hM0jYQr5mv9BU/6oKUWgdedM8a5BDQMQtWF5e5NMSh/6GlzSMfscnk1Sc4W+Pb0ijEWKmgNJfGsQigc6A=
    Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using PKCS #7 padding. This scheme will always add bytes to the plaintext, even if it's already block-aligned.

In your case, the plaintext is being padded with sixteen bytes with the value '16'. Therefore you get an extra block in your ciphertext.

If your other code is not expecting this, then it's not using PKCS #7 padding. Or the implementation is broken.

Comment: Duncan, thanks for the quick response.
Following your answer, I was able to find the following links:
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)] and
[http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652#section-6.3]